# error:a hook ('orm') failed to load when lifting sails app using mongo DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

I get this error: a hook ('orm') failed to load when trying to lift a sails app using mongoDB. This my connections.js file:

```
module.exports.connections = {
  mongodb: {
    adapter   : 'sails-mongo',
    host      : 'localhost',
    port      : 27017,
    database  : 'mydb1'
  }
};
```

And this is my models.js file:

```
module.exports.models = {
  connection: 'mongodb'
};
```

And this is my local.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  connections: {
    mongodb: {
      host      : 'localhost',
      port      : 27017,
      database  : 'mydb1'
    }
  }
}
```

Sails v 0.10.1

Any idea why this could be happening?

Thanks

Comment: did you install sails-mongo? (`npm install sails-mongo`)

Comment: @Xinzz yes and it was successful

Comment: Are there no other error messages, perhaps pertaining to connecting to the database?  Can you connect to the database in the console using the `mongo` client?

Comment: @sgress454 How do I do that?

Comment: Do you [have MongoDB installed](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads) on your system?

Comment: Assuming that MongoDB server is running on your system, you should be able to type `mongo` in your console to test that you can connect.  If that fails, the issue is likely that you need to start the server.  A quick Google for "start mongo server <your system type>" should help there.

Comment: sgress454 give you a good hint. Apart from that please delete the connection in your `local.js`. That isn't necessary and haven to connections with the same name could also be a problem

Comment: It's a problem with the MongoDB itself that I've been trying to fix since @sgress454 suggested that I should check if mongo is working. So when I fix this issue I'll either update the post or delete it if works. Thans alot for your help.

Comment: i got the very same problem. i can connect to mongodb via mongo command, everything works fine in the terminal. were you able to resolve your problem?

Comment: for me it was a problem with mongodb itself, I wasn't even able to connect via mongo shell.

Comment: i see. i was too able to resolve the problem. one must not use an '@' sign in the password because it is a delimiter and messes up the connection string lol.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message. Usually there are more details.

Comment: @mandeep_m91 it was a problem with mongodb itself and I fixed it. Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All you need to do is start your mongodb.

Navigate to : path_to_your_mongodb_installation_folder\MongoDB\bin\mongod.exe
example : C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin

Let us know if this helps!

Comment: could've been commented

Comment: this is my first response ever on stackoverflow, I'll remember next time.

Comment: run mongod.exe then mongo.exe

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
models: {
    connect: 'your_mongod_db_adapter_name'
}
```

in both env/development and env/production fixed the problem for me

Answer (score -1):

For those if it didn't work in heroku after deploying, try to change the node js, sails, sails-mongo versions and check.

It worked for me after changing the versions to the below:

1.nodejs - 14.15.1

2.sails  - ^1.5.2

3.sails-mongo -  ^2.0.0